# js beginner- how to parse through all child nodes immediately at one level lower than a DOM node in a web page

Tags: javascript

I understand that for a web page's node stored in a variable named 'parent', I can obtain all its child nodes using the command

```
var children=parent.childNodes;
```

I have 2 questions here--

(a) Will the above line of code only provide the nodes that are immediate children? Or will nodes even lower than immediate children also be stored in 'children' variable?

(b) How can I parse through each node in the 'children' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) It will return only direct children (but, of course each child may contain children)

b)

```
var children = parent.childNodes;

for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
{
    var singleChild = children[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) It will return only immediate children, but they in their turn will contain all of it's child nodes...and so on.

2)

```
for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++)
{
    children[i].......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes, only immediate childnodes are listed

b) using ES5 magic for example

```
[].forEach.call(children, function( node ) {
    console.log( node );
});
```

So we could have a recurive call, to loop over all child-nodes:

```
(function _loop( current ) {
    [].forEach.call( current.children, function( node ) {
        if( node.children.length ) {
            _loop( node );
        }
        else {
           console.log( node );
        }
    });
}( children ));
```